# SQL select count distinct + SUM

Tags: sql

In my database Shop I have many products: books, pens, pencils. I'd like to sum total price of every kind - meaning: I have 20 pencils 2 dollars each, so I'd like to obtain value 40 dollars. For 10 books 5 dollars each - 50 dollars etc. I was trying with distinct, sum and group by, but without success so far.

```
select price, name, count(*) from basket_items group by price, name
```

gives me only number of items of each distinct price.

Comment: I assume the downvote came because of the lack of *real* examples what you tried >without success so far.

Comment: please add sample data,Expected result any query you have tried so far.also tag the relevant RDBMS.check here on how to start asking :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @TheGameiswar ... my first reaction was...hey this isn't SO's "How to answer a question" page. but for SQL questions, this is exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(price) from Shop 
GROUP BY products
```

Comment: what's products in this example?

Comment: doesn't the products are assumed to be `books, pens, pencils.` in your example

Comment: Suggest updating the answer to use OP's table name and columns and/or clarify with some commentary

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select name as Product, sum(price) as Sum_Total_Price from basket_items group by name
```

The query is getting products and summing up the prices for each product.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, sum(costs) 
from tbl
group by id
```

Comment: What is `id` in your example? `id` field is usually primary key and that by definition is unique, so grouping by it is useless.

Comment: id in my case is id code of a product. in your table (like i understand) there is a lots of rows with the same product id's,  there for it shouldn't be defind like a primary key